# Модальное окно после того как будут отмечены все input-radio

Tags: javascript

Делаю опрос для клиента, необходимо выводить результаты опроса в модальном окне например только после того как в каждом ряду будет выбрано по одному из пяти радиокнопок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как я могу это отследить? я думал ввести счетчик который будет после каждого события добавлять к переменной +1 и сравнивать это значение с другой переменной, в которой будет указано общее количество вопросов, но если человек в одной строке поменяет радиокнопку, результат будет неверным. есть ли еще какие нибудь способы это сделать?

Comment: Возможно тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553197/how-to-check-if-a-radio-button-in-each-group-is-checked-in-jquery есть подходящие варианты проверки, а вызывать проверку можно по событию выбора ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, достаточно простой пример, просто считать внутри каждого блока выбран ли в нем input или нет:

```js
$('[data-box]').on('click', 'input', function() {
  if($('[data-box] input:checked').length == 5) {
    alert('Это все!');
    console.log('Это все!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-box>
  <div class="box__title">Заголовок 1</div>
  <input type="radio" name="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="1" />
</div>

<div class="box" data-box>
  <div class="box__title">Заголовок 2</div>
  <input type="radio" name="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="2" />
</div>

<div class="box" data-box>
  <div class="box__title">Заголовок 3</div>
  <input type="radio" name="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="3" />
</div>

<div class="box" data-box>
  <div class="box__title">Заголовок 4</div>
  <input type="radio" name="4" />
  <input type="radio" name="4" />
  <input type="radio" name="4" />
  <input type="radio" name="4" />
  <input type="radio" name="4" />
</div>

<div class="box" data-box>
  <div class="box__title">Заголовок 5</div>
  <input type="radio" name="5" />
  <input type="radio" name="5" />
  <input type="radio" name="5" />
  <input type="radio" name="5" />
  <input type="radio" name="5" />
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это решение намного лучше моего, я не додумался при каждом событии получать псевдо-массив элементов  и сравнивать его по длине с заданным числом